# Git Clone Failure

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a Linux-based Amazon AMI which houses a Git repository. I want to `git clone` that repository to my local OSX machine (which also has Git installed).

The repository lives on the Amazon box at `/home/ec2-user/my_test_repo`. Inside of the `my_test_repo` directory is the `.git` directory.

On my OSX machine I can successfully SSH to the machine hosting the repo as `ec2-user` and I can execute lots of bash commands. So, I know SSH works. However, the following command doesn't work when I execute it from my OSX machine:

```
git clone ssh://ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/my_test_repo.git
```

I get the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'my_test_repo'...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/227804/why-cant-i-ssh-into-my-new-ec2-instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that you can't login to the server:

> ```
> Cloning into 'my_test_repo'...
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.
> ```

You need to get this command working first:

```
ssh ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This problem has nothing to do with Git, you need to get `ssh` working with public key authentication.

The second problem is that the path to your repository is probably wrong. If your repository on the server is in the `.git` directory *inside* `/home/ec2-user/my_test_repo`, then the URL would be:

```
git clone ssh://ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/my_test_repo/.git
```

Notice the end part is `my_test_repo/.git`, because it should correspond to the filesystem path of the directory containing a Git repository. A Git repository contains files like `HEAD`, `config`, and directories like `objects`, `refs`, `hooks`, and some others.

As such, it looks like `my_test_repo` is a so-called *working tree*. If you clone from `my_test_repo/.git`, you won't be able to push to it, because git doesn't allow pushing to repositories with working tree. It only allows pushing to a so-called *bare repository*, without a working tree. You can create a bare repository from your existing non-bare repository with these commands:

```
git clone --bare my_test_repo my_test_repo.git
```

After you do this, your original URL should work, because now the path to the Git repository is really `my_test_repo.git`, instead of `my_test_repo/.git`. You don't need the `my_test_repo` working tree anymore, you can delete it.

Finally, you could simplify the repository URL like this:

```
git clone ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:my_test_repo.git
```

Comment: You're right, and actually my original answer completely missed the point. I fixed it now.

Comment: This helped me tremendously...the URL to download a remote git repository through SSH is a lot harder to get right than it should be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this working, **with a lot of help from @janos** (see his comments above).

First, you need to get ssh working with public key authentication. This has nothing to do with Git.

In Terminal, on the OSX client machine, I entered the following command: `ssh-keygen -t dsa`, which generates the SSH keys on my local OSX machine. For each one of the prompts, you can enter actual values, or just press ENTER (entering values allows you to customize and make the SSH process more secure). I just pressed ENTER.

Next,I copied the newly generated **~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub** file (make 100% sure it's the file with .pub at the end) to the remote Amazon EC2 server. However, I found this process to be a little different than how most online tutorials explain (I think because of the somewhat unique use of .pem files for EC2 instances).

In Terminal on the OSX machine, I `cd` into the directory containing my .pem file, and then I entered the following command: `scp -i JPo.pem ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com:.ssh/authorized_keys`

At this point, ssh with public key authentication should now be working between the client OSX machine and the remote Amazon EC2 instance.

And now comes the Git stuff, which is pretty basic. I entered the following command: `git clone ssh://ec2-user@ec2-54-81-229-189.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/my_test_repo/.git`

And done. It worked!

Comment: There are plenty of articles on the internet about setting up ssh access with public key, that's why I didn't explain it in detail. Keep in mind that you won't be able to push to this non-bare repository. You should follow the steps I gave you to create a bare repository and work with that instead.

Comment: @janos Gotcha. I wasn't aware that the "bare" info was required to be able to push to the repository. I'll give it a shot (as you described), and then I'll edit my instructions above accordingly. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: That requirement is because when you push, the remote working tree will get out of sync with the repository. Normally Git has no way of ensuring the consistency of the remote working tree and its repository, that's why it refuses pushes to a non-bare repo by default.